# Is there a way to further optimize this code?

Tags: c++, optimization, vector, set

> 2289, LeetCode. Steps To make array non-decreasing
> You are given a 0-indexed integer array nums. In one step, remove all elements `nums[i]` where `nums[i - 1] > nums[i]` for all `0 < i < nums.length`.
>
> Return the number of steps performed until nums becomes a non-decreasing array.
> Input: nums = `[5,3,4,4,7,3,6,11,8,5,11]`
> Output: `3`
> Explanation: The following are the steps performed:
>
> - Step 1: [5,**3**,4,4,7,**3**,6,11,**8**,**5**,11] becomes [5,4,4,7,6,11,11]
> - Step 2: [5,**4**,4,7,**6**,11,11] becomes [5,4,7,11,11]
> - Step 3: [5,**4**,7,11,11] becomes [5,7,11,11]
>   `[5,7,11,11]` is a non-decreasing array. Therefore, we return 3.

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    // 84/87
    int totalSteps(vector<int>& nums) {
        int i;
        int steps = 0;
        
        
        set <int> indexes;

        while(1)
        {
            // marking indexes where found breaking of order
            for(i=1; i<nums.size(); i++) if(nums[i-1]>nums[i]) indexes.insert(i);
            // deleting them
            if(indexes.size()==0) break; // vector is only increasing
            for (auto it = indexes.rbegin(); it != indexes.rend(); ++it) nums.erase(nums.begin() + *it);
            
            indexes.clear();
            ++steps;
        }

    return steps;
    }
};
```

I am currently passing 84/87 tests on leetcode, with the remaining ones exceeding the time limit.

Comment: `for (auto it = indexes.rbegin(); it != indexes.rend(); ++it) nums.erase(nums.begin() + *it);` --  Imagine if there are thousands of elements, and say, 40 items to erase.  For every individual call to `erase`, the vector has to shrink, causing a move/copy of possibly thousands of elements.  So in that case, you are shrinking the vector 40 times -- do you see how this can cause a slowdown?  If you're going to do down this route, try *moving* the elements to erase to the end of the vector, keeping track of where the erased elements start, and doing just one single `erase` call.

Comment: Yes learn a bit more about the standard library <algorithm> header. `std::remove_if` might be an option. Maybe also learn a bit more C++... passing vector's by value is going to copy everything, so learn to pass by (const) reference.

Comment: Are you trying to learn C++ by doing algorithm puzzles? Not really recommended...

Comment: I am doing it for fun, it partially replaced gaming for me, and in essence remains the same thing, a way to enjoy(or not) my free time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution with linear time and space complexity. Let us consider the number of steps to remove the element at any index `i`. There must exist an index `j` such that `j < i` and `nums[j] > nums[i]`. More specifically, the largest `j` (i.e. the closest larger element on the left) that satisfies this condition will cause the deletion of the element at index `i`.

All the elements between indexes `j` and `i` must be removed before `i` becomes adjacent to `j` and can be removed. Thus, the number of steps to remove `i` is one more than the maximum number of steps to remove any element between `j` and `i`.

We can maintain a monotonic stack of indexes (with elements in increasing order from top to bottom) for the full solution.

```cpp
int totalSteps(vector<int>& nums) {
    stack<int> s;
    int ans = 0;
    vector<int> steps(nums.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
        int curr = 1;
        while (!s.empty() && nums[s.top()] <= nums[i]) 
            curr = max(curr, 1 + steps[s.top()]), s.pop();
        if (!s.empty()) ans = max(ans, steps[i] = curr);
        s.push(i);
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: This is the way the problem was intended to be solved, and obviously the fun lies in it. 
I will stick to this one. Thanks to everyone who took their time to think and comment on my post!